# Alert message and button array

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm creating an iphone app that at one page before you can move on to the next you have to select a button or an alert will pop up.

```
.h
<UIAlertViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttons;

.m

-(BOOL)validateTag:(NSArray *)buttons {

[self.buttons enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj) {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)obj;

    if (button !=  button.enabled){
       return NO; 
   }

   return YES;

 } ];

}



 -(IBAction)save:(id)sender{


    if (![self validateTag:_buttons]) {
        [self alertMessage:@"Invalid ":@"Please choose a Tag"];

        return;

    }
   else {
```

....display other viewcontroller

```
}
```

The error I'm getting is

```
`Incompatible pointer types sending bool to parameter of type void`
```

on line
 `[self.buttons enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj)`

Anyways of getting around this?

Thanks.

Comment: `if (button !=  button.enabled)` what does this do?

Comment: It should then bring up the alert message

Comment: the method takes a parameter and never uses it!!! And which line giving you error...I am unable to understand

Comment: May be in your .h file you are using -(void)validateTag:(NSArray *)buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The block you're using doesn't have a return type, so you can't return the BOOL value from there. You should use a `__block` variable instead:

```
-(BOOL)validateTag:(NSArray *)buttons
{
    __block BOOL result = NO;

    [self.buttons enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)obj;

        if (button.enabled) {
            result = YES;
            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works but I think it'll always return the same result? I keep on getting either an alert for both button enabled and not enabled or if there's no alert there's no alert for either.

Comment: You could change to this to debug what's going on: `if (button.enabled) { NSLog(@"%d enabled - stopping", idx); result = YES; *stop = YES; } else { NSLog(@"%d not enabled", idx); }`

Comment: :) aw wonderful! thank you. Is there a dummies book on this stuff?